# If Statements with Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate some weighted percentages with the following criteria:

```
If X=70% then I multiply 80% of 30%
If X=75% then I multiply 100% of 30%
If X=80% then I add 10% to the 30%
Anything beyond 80% is at most 40%.
```

How do I calculate what this percentage will be if say for example, X = 73%? It's expected to be over 80%.

```
1. If X<70%
2. If 70%<=X<75%
3. If 75%<=X<80%

if X = 69% it will be less than 24% (less than 80% of 30%) 
if X = 73%, the percentage will be between 24%-30% (between 80% and 100% of 30%), how can I determine how this is scaled? 
if X = 81%, then it will be at most 40%
```

Comment: Please show expected results.  Is 80% of 30% equal  to 24% ??

Comment: Yes 
    if X = 69% it will be less than 24% (less than 80% of 30%) 
    if X = 73%, the percentage will be between 24%-30% (between 80% and 100% of 30%), how can I determine how this is scaled? 
    if X = 81%, then it will be at most 40%

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to avoid the IF statement and replace it with INDEX/MATCH because of its greater flexibility. Basically, you have two multipliers. One varies between 30% and 40%, the other between 80% and 100% of the result of the first. Use the MATCH function to determine the bracket, for example, `=MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,72.5,75,77.5,80,82.5,85},1)`. Here your example of 73% is found in A1. The numbers between curly braces allow for 9 categories: less than 65%, 65% to less than 70%, 70% to less than 72.5% ... and 85% and over. There can be as many brackets as you like, using any numbers that suit your needs. Just make sure that they are in ascending order.
Next, create the index, for example, `=INDEX({30,30,31,32,33,35,38,40,42},5)`. The key point here is that there should be as many elements in the index as there are brackets in the MATCH function. My above sample INDEX will return 33 because the 5th index element is specified. In the formula below the 5 is replaced by the MATCH function.

```
=INDEX({30,30,31,32,33,35,38,40,42},MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,72.5,75,77.5,80,82.5,85},1))
```

This function will return 32(%) if A1=72%. Adjust the Index and/or Match arrays to return the result you need. Divide the result by 100 to convert the result to percent.
Given the flexibility of the suggested method I think you may not need to resort to twin multiplications. However, if your system requires it, just build the second multiplier in the same way as the first. `=INDEX({75,80,85,90,95,100},MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,75,80,85},1))` Then multiply both with each other.

```
=INDEX({75,80,85,90,95,100},MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,75,80,85},1))*INDEX({30,30,31,32,33,35,38,40,42},MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,72.5,75,77.5,80,82.5,85},1))/10^2
```

Observe the division by 100 at the end which converts the result (here, based on A1=73%) of 32 * 85 = 2720 into 27.2. Change the divisor to 10^4 in order to obtain 27.2%

Comment: This is an interesting approach but I'm not sure if it is correct: if X = 69% it will be less than 24% (less than 80% of 30%) 
if X = 73%, the percentage will be between 24%-30% (between 80% and 100% of 30%), how can I determine how this is scaled? 
if X = 81%, then it will be at most 40%

Comment: I set the brackets haphazardly and focused on explaining how you can set them correctly yourself. I think your system makes life unnecessarily difficult by demanding to calculate on 2 levels, like 80% of 30%, 100% of 30%, 80% of 40% or 100% of 40%. With an unlimited number of brackets you can translate that into 24%, 30%, 32% and 40%. Thanks to the greater transparency of this way you can see immediately that the step from 30% to 32% may be smaller than intended.

Comment: With a single Index/Match you set the brackets in the Match array =MATCH($A$1*100,{0,65,70,72.5,75,77.5,80,82.5,85},1). Make sure the first number =0 to define a range smaller than the next number (0.65 in this case) Set the Index range to match element by element, e.g. INDEX({30,30,31,32,33,35,38,40,42}. The first number matches the first bracket, the second the second etc. One Index element for each Match element.